# How do I get the annotations from the active Tab

Tags: pdftron

Currently, when I get the annotations from the annotationManager, they are coming back empty for the current document, do we need to manage annotationMangers for each tab?

```
const allAnnotList = annotationManager.getAnnotationsList();
```

Anyone with any experience using PDFTron tab view for multiple documents.

1. Does each tab have a documentViewer or is this global and updated when the tab is changed.
2. Does the annotationManager hold all annotations or just for the current documentViewer

I have narrowed down the issue to the below function call:

```
currentAnnotationManger.exportAnnotations
```

currentAnnotationManger.exportAnnotations
Confirmed we have a list of annotations below:

> 

```js
[
  {
    "BU": true,
    "Subject": "client-Client 1-0",
    "WF": 1,
    "Gz": 261,
    "Hz": 197,
    "Ru": 96,
    "Qu": 32,
    "Rotation": 0,
    "le": {
      "x": 309,
      "y": 213
    },
    "AO": 50.59644256269407,
    "Dz": false,
    "DO": false,
    "EO": false,
    "ni": {
      "trn-annot-maintain-aspect-ratio": "true",
      "trn-unrotated-rect": "261,626,357,658"
    },
    "Bz": true,
    "yO": false,
    "UF": false,
    "Pu": false,
    "zO": false,
    "TF": false,
    "NoZoom": false,
    "NoRotate": false,
    "FO": true,
    "Nm": null,
    "TO": "Agent Id : 62b11e644180cb09e786ec7d",
    "iG": "2022-10-28T03:47:54.535Z",
    "hA": "d9b4efdc-af38-d203-5a41-0139451aecd4",
    "xG": true,
    "fp": false,
    "KP": false,
    "iQ": {},
    "Wk": [],
    "gh": null,
    "uE": null,
    "ZK": null,
    "qr": [],
    "Uo": {},
    "To": {},
    "CO": null,
    "GO": null,
    "yj": null,
    "zj": null,
    "aQ": 1,
    "Y3": null,
    "eP": "2022-10-28T03:47:50.793Z",
    "CA": null,
    "_xsi:type": "Stamp",
    "oi": "Draft",
    "Cy": "Draft",
    "Ya": null,
    "Vw": 1,
    "canvas": {},
    "K7": "bold italic 30px sans-serif",
    "ToolName": "AnnotationCreateRubberStamp",
    "image": {}
  },
  {
    "BU": true,
    "Subject": "agent",
    "WF": 1,
    "Gz": 200,
    "Hz": 300,
    "Ru": 96,
    "Qu": 32,
    "Rotation": 0,
    "le": {
      "x": 248,
      "y": 316
    },
    "AO": 50.59644256269407,
    "Dz": false,
    "DO": false,
    "EO": false,
    "ni": {
      "trn-annot-maintain-aspect-ratio": "true",
      "trn-unrotated-rect": "200,523,296,555"
    },
    "Bz": true,
    "yO": false,
    "UF": false,
    "Pu": false,
    "zO": false,
    "TF": false,
    "NoZoom": false,
    "NoRotate": false,
    "FO": true,
    "Nm": null,
    "TO": "Agent Id : 62b11e644180cb09e786ec7d",
    "iG": "2022-10-28T03:47:54.535Z",
    "hA": "58dc723e-da36-5f4e-16d5-fe6ae32f5252",
    "xG": true,
    "fp": false,
    "KP": false,
    "iQ": {},
    "Wk": [],
    "gh": null,
    "uE": null,
    "ZK": null,
    "qr": [],
    "Uo": {},
    "To": {},
    "CO": null,
    "GO": null,
    "yj": null,
    "zj": null,
    "aQ": 1,
    "Y3": null,
    "eP": "2022-10-28T03:47:53.499Z",
    "CA": null,
    "_xsi:type": "Stamp",
    "oi": "Draft",
    "Cy": "Draft",
    "Ya": null,
    "Vw": 1,
    "canvas": {},
    "K7": "bold italic 30px sans-serif",
    "ToolName": "AnnotationCreateRubberStamp",
    "image": {}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your questions

**Does each tab have a documentViewer or is this global and updated when the tab is changed.**

There is only one active "documentViewer" that get updated when tab are changed. Currently tab data is stored in the [UI.TabManager](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/UI.TabManager.html). The UI part of the codebase is open sourced so you can see what the TabManager does in the link below

https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-ui/blob/8.9/src/helpers/TabManager.js

**Does the annotationManager hold all annotations or just for the current documentViewer**

There is only one annotationManager that hold the current annotations for the active tab. When you change tab, the current data (annotations, scroll position, etc) are stored in the TabManager and get restored when you switch back to that tab.

Currently there isn't an API to get annotations for non active tab, you'll need to get it before the tab change, during the [beforeTabChanged](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/UI.html#event:beforeTabChanged) event (it sounds like that what you are doing now)

Best Regards

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you so much for the clarifications, are you able to run your eyes over the below function, the  currentAnnotationManger.exportAnnotations is coming back with none of the added annotations.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to the active tab not having any annotations so when calling :

```
currentAnnotationManger.exportAnnotations
```

It was returning null, even though I was passing in annotation list.
Solution: exportAnnotations before the current tab changes focus.

Answer (score 0):

So to add to this discussion, calling below function works just fine when I'm saving, so is triggered from an event from a button, but when called within the beforeTabChanged event the currentAnnotationManger.exportAnnotations call is coming back empty.

```js
async function getAnnotationsStrings(documentViewer) {
        const currentAnnotationManger = documentViewer.getAnnotationManager();
        // Get all the annotations
        const allAnnotList = currentAnnotationManger.getAnnotationsList();
        const flkAnnotationList = getAllFlkAnnotations(allAnnotList);
        const flkAnnotationString = await currentAnnotationManger.exportAnnotations({
            links: false,
            widgets: false,
            annotList: flkAnnotationList
        });
        console.log('flkAnnotationString ' + flkAnnotationString);
        return { flkAnnotationString };
    }
```